# Python OpenSSL: How to create an X509Name object

Tags: pyopenssl

I need to filter incoming X509 certificates by issuer, and I am using Pyhton's OpenSSL.crypto for this. However, I did not find how to create an X509Name object as a constant, which I need to compare with the value I get from cert.get_issuer().

Comment: To phrase the question differently: is it safe to do string comparison on X509Name objects? I recall that in LDAP string-rendering on DNs can be implementation dependent in corner cases.

Answer (score 1):

Best thing I can think of, for you to create a new X509Name is to use

```
name = crypto.X509Name(crypto.X509().get_subject())
```

and subsequently populate the attributes via

```
name.__setattr__(att_name, attr_value)
```

However, for comparison alone, better to use the hash() builtin function of the class, that returns a hash for the whole name, or do a per-attribute comparison